# linq Contains but less

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a list to search a table,

```
List<long> searchListIds = new List<long>();
searchListIds.Add(1);
searchListIds.Add(2);

List<long> searchListFieldValues = new List<long>();
searchListFieldValues.Add(100);
searchListFieldValues.Add(50);
```

and my query is:

```
var adsWithRelevantadFields =
    from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
    group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
    where searchListIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
        && searchListFieldValues.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Contains(i))
    select adAdFields.Key;
```

everything is ok, but now:   i need to get all records that meet less than searchListFieldValues. i mean:

**all adId that have `(listId == 1)&(listFieldValue <100)` AND `(listId == 2)&(listFieldValue <50)`**

contains part must change to something like **contains-less**

---

**example:**

cwContext.tblAdFields:

```
id              1     2     3     4    5    6    7
adId            1     2     1     2    3    3    3
listId          1     1     2     2    1    2    3
listfieldValue  100   100   50    50   100  49   10
```

Now if I want to get `(listId == 1)&(listFieldValue ==100) AND (listId == 2)&(listFieldValue ==50)` my code works, and return id adId: `1,2`

but I can't get

**all adId that have `(listId == 1)&(listFieldValue ==100) AND (listId == 2)&(listFieldValue <50)`**

it must return 3

Comment: So size of both lists is always the same?

Comment: @Anatolii Gabuza yes, i heard about concat but i couldn't use, any way problem is now is contain-less

Comment: Can you give an example of input data (cwContext.tblAdFields) and the result you expect from that data (adsWithRelevantadFields)?

Comment: @mrzli why not, how tell you?

Comment: I   think you're looking for `.Any(i => i< someValue)` instead of `.Contains()`

Comment: With the data you supplied, and if I understood what you are trying to do correctly, you would not get any `adId`. All entries that have `listId = 1` have `listfieldValue = 100`, so none is <100, and all entries that have `listId = 2` have `listfieldValue = 50`, so none is <50. What result do you expect for this data?

Comment: @mrzli you are right, let me change my example

Comment: @mohammadadibi You may have 2 errors in your question. First: you would get the result 1, 2, 3 (not only 1, 2) for the "equals" condition, because of entry 5. Second: in the bolded line, did you mean to write `listFieldValue < 100` instead of `listFieldValue == 100` The way it is written now you would get the result 1, 2, 3. I'm only trying to correct you so I know I understand what you are trying to do (or you correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @mrzli in equal i get 1,2. because 3 has listId=2, but doesn't have listFieldVlaue = 50.///listFieldValue == 100 is correct also it can be less or more depends on user data. thanks any way, let me check your answer it takes time to understand for me.

Comment: @mohammadadibi Entry with id=5 has **adId=3** AND has **listId=1** AND **listFieldValue=100** which satisfies the condition, so you get 3 in the result. If istFieldValue == 100 is correct in the bolded line then you get **1, 2 and 3**, not only 3 as you specified.

Comment: @mrzli you get the point, yes you are right, but consider group by and all, it return ** all adId that have all search conditions **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try changing `Contains` to `Any`, but I'm not sure if LINQ to Entities will translate it correctly into proper SQL statement.

```
var adsWithRelevantadFields =
    from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
    group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
    where searchListIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
        && searchListFieldValues.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Any(x => x < i))
    select adAdFields.Key;
```

Comment: THAT'S GREAT, THANK YOU, just let me to double check, and mark answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example that should work if I understood you correctly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> searchListIds = new List<int>
        {
            1,
            2,
        };

        List<int> searchListFieldValues = new List<int>
        {
            100,
            50,
        };

        List<Tuple<int, int>> searchParameters = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchListIds.Count; i++)
        {
            searchParameters.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(searchListIds[i], searchListFieldValues[i]));
        }

        List<AdField> adFields = new List<AdField>
        {
            new AdField(1, 1, 1, 100),
            new AdField(2, 2, 1, 100),
            new AdField(3, 1, 2, 50),
            new AdField(4, 2, 2, 50),
            new AdField(5, 3, 1, 100),
            new AdField(6, 3, 2, 49),
            new AdField(7, 3, 3, 10)
        };

        var result = adFields.Where(af => searchParameters.Any(sp => af.ListId == sp.Item1 && af.ListFieldValue < sp.Item2)).Select(af => af.AdId).Distinct();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public class AdField
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public int AdId { get; private set; }
        public int ListId { get; private set; }
        public int ListFieldValue { get; private set; }

        public AdField(int id, int adId, int listId, int listFieldValue)
        {
            Id = id;
            AdId = adId;
            ListId = listId;
            ListFieldValue = listFieldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't consider "group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields" we must work on "adAdFields" not "adField or tblAdFields" we group them before, now must work on grouped fields.

Comment: @mohammadadibi It is not clear to me what exactly you want to accomplish. If I don't know that I cannot help you. I don't know what the purpose of this grouping is in your example.

Comment: ok let me explain, i have tblAdFields, each advertisement, has many fields(record in table) for example we have 3 list(home_room, home_price, home_wallpaper), then some list has value, suppose home_room:1,2,3.../ then each ad parts to tblAdFields. now we want to search every AD has listId(home_room) and listFieldValue(2 room, or more than 2 room,or ...) / in this case we need first group adId, then search, filter them.

Comment: your tuple was great, it helps me, but my problem is less, great, between for grouped parameters, if you see my code everything is ok before less or great

Answer (score 0):

First, you're probably looking for functionality of [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Contains()`. Another thing is that if your search criteria consists of *two items* - use *one* list of [`Tuple<int,int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of two lists. In this case you will e able to efficiently search by combination of *listId* and *fieldValue*:

```
var result = from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
             where searchParams.Any(sp => adField.listId == sp.Item1 && adField.listFieldValue < sp.Item2)
             group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
             select adAdField.Key;
```

Comment: thanks i think your answer is like @mezli, any way you are right, Tuple  is better, but i didn't hear about it before.

Comment: you didn't consider "group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields" we must work on "adAdFields" not "adField or tblAdFields" we group them before, now must work on grouped fields.